# Why are exceptions not working?(Capture images from IP cameras)

Tags: python, opencv, exception, ip-camera

This is my code, everything works fine and I can get the image from the ipcamera, but my problem is when the camera disconnects for some reason, I want the code to wait for the connection again! But the code doesn't end, it doesn't continue!
Edit it:

```
import csv
import cv2
import time
import queue, threading
import requests.exceptions 
from time import sleep
import requests

with open('bin/Load/option_1.csv',encoding="utf-8") as option1 :
    reader = csv.reader(option1)
    option1 = list(reader)
    ipcam1=option1[0][0]
    camUser1=option1[1][0]
    camPass1=option1[2][0]
class VideoCapture:

  def __init__(self, name):
    self.cap = cv2.VideoCapture(name)
    self.cap.open(name)
    self.q = queue.Queue()
    t = threading.Thread(target=self._reader)
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()

  # read frames as soon as they are available, keeping only most recent one
  def _reader(self):
    while True:
      ret, frame = self.cap.read()
      if not ret:
        break
      if not self.q.empty():
        try:
          self.q.get_nowait()   # discard previous (unprocessed) frame
        except queue.Empty:
          pass
      self.q.put(frame)

  def read(self):
    return self.q.get()

url1='rtsp://'+camUser1+':'+camPass1+'@'+ipcam1+':554/Streaming/channels/1/'
cap1= VideoCapture(url1)

while True:
        try:

            time.sleep(0)   # simulate time between events
            sleep(0.18)
            frame = cap1.read()
            with open("tools/croping_image_1.csv",newline="",encoding="utf-8") as cropi1:
                reader = csv.reader(cropi1)
                cropi1 = list(reader)
            frame = frame[int(cropi1[0][0]):int(cropi1[1][0]), int(cropi1[2][0]):int(cropi1[3][0])]
            cv2.imwrite("screen1.jpg", frame)

        except requests.Timeout:
            time.sleep(4)
            print("one camera timeouterr")
        except ConnectionError:
            time.sleep(4)
            print("one camera not ConnectionError")
```

Comment: Why are you expecting to get exceptions? In OpenCV we read a frame: `ret, frame = self.cap.read()`, and `if not ret` then the camera is (probably) disconnected.

Comment: Hi Rotem, when I disconnect the network cable from the camera, I expect an exception to be thrown or the code to be closed, but neither.

Comment: As far as I know, when using `cv2.VideoCapture` there are no exceptions. There are two thinks to check: `cap.isOpened()` and the returned value of `ret` after : `ret, frame = cap.read()`. When the return value is `False`, execute `cap.release()` and `cap = cv2.VideoCapture(...)`. (I don't know if it covers all the cases).

Comment: dear rotem, It seems correct, can you edit my code, thank you very much

Comment: I am not going to edit your code. I don't think I can make a good answer out of it.